# How can I create 600+ copies of a word doc, using a naming convention from a spreadsheet?

Tags: vba, macos, automation, ms-word

I have a list of 600 names in a spreadsheet, and I want to quickly create a Word Doc for each with the name in the filename.

I work on a Mac.

Comment: The version of Mac Office is important if you are seeking a VBA solution. What Mac Office version are you running?

Comment: What do you mean by *"with the name in the filename"*? If one of the names in the spreadsheet is `"Bill"`, you want to create a Word document called `"Something-Bill-Something.doc"`? And what is supposed to be in the Word document - I mean what is the content of the document?

Comment: This answer does something very close to that, but your question is unclear: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52073136/2836621

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula for the required commands.

The result of the formula should be:

```
cp "/path/to/original.docx" "/path/to/copy-filename.docx"
```

So for example, if you want the copy to be called "copy-" then the contents of the `A` column, the formula might be:

```
="cp ""/path/to/original.docx"" ""/path/to/copy-" & A1 & ".docx"""
```

Then fill down the formula down the spreadsheet to create the commands.

Then you can copy the formula result and paste it into a text editor to check it is correct. Once you are satisfied it is correct, you can paste it into a terminal window and the commands will be executed.

If this is a one-off task, this is what I suggest. If you need to do this hourly then you should probably do something different involving a VBA macro.