# Searching in Finder from Selection

Tags: excel, macos, shell, applescript, automator

Usually I get an excel spreadsheet with dozens of filenames, for which I then need to go and search individually.

> [Spreadhseet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUUqD.png)

Is there a way that I could simply:

1. Select All filenames in e.g. **row A** of Excel,
2. then Search for all these files on **"This Mac"**
3. then Copy all found files into the **New Folder** on the **Desktop**

So far I've tried the first part of searching and this is what i get :a)

> [Automator with Variable. But the problem is, it only searches for 1 file from selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS3oT.png)

b)

> [Automator with Shell Script (Copy to Clipboard > Open Finder > CMD+F (to highlight Search dialog) > CMD+V). It opens a new Finder window, but it doesn't paste the clipboard into search dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raArX.png)

c) `/usr/bin/pbcopy`

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "f" using {command down}
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
    end tell    
    return input
end run`
```

End result, is same as option b). I was planning to run this in Automator as a '*Service*', which I could later assign to Keyboard Shortcut.

I am pretty sure there should be a simple shell option for this - any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your files are called `9134934` and `4244650`? And they could be anywhere on your disk? Why don't you just drop the spreadsheet on an app on your desktop rather than opening it and selecting the first column?

Comment: Thanks Mark for the reply! Yep, the filenames are usually up to 8 digits long. With extension of  either .jpg , .tif or .tiff. They can be anywhere on my machine.  Usually when I receive this spreadsheet, it might have many more comments, filenames in other rows which I dont need to search. By select-searching, it would save me the hassle of creating another spreadsheet.

Comment: Is the extension in the file (it's not shown), or do you have to try all 3 possible ones?

Comment: There is no reason to specify filetype, as those images with those 8 digits are the only files on that machine. The extensions are omitted in the spreadsheet. The 8 digits is all what we use to search for these images in the Spotlight. I am simply looking how to quickly copy everything into clipboard, and paste it into Finders Search dialog. If something like this would be possible in shell - even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a `bash` script that does what you want. You would basically select a bunch of filenames in Excel, or any other app, and copy them to the clipboard with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. After that you need to run the script and it will take items from the clipboard and search for TIFF or JPEG images that match that name and copy them to a directory on your Desktop called `Selected Files`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get contents of clipboard into bash array
files=( $(pbpaste) )

# Create output directory - no checks for already existing or already containing files
OUTDIR="$HOME/Desktop/Selected Files"
mkdir -p "$OUTDIR"

# Iterate through fetching files
for ((i=0;i<${#files[@]};i++)) ; do
   name=${files[i]}
   result=$( mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == \"${name}.*\" && (kMDItemKind==\"TIFF image\" || kMDItemKind==\"JPEG image\")" )
   if [ -f "$result" ]; then
      echo $name: $result
      cp "$result" "$OUTDIR"
   else
      echo ERROR: Searched for: $name, found $result
   fi
done
```

---

I am not sure of your level of familiarity with `bash`, so you may be able to ignore the following...

Make a new directory for your own scripts:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/scripts
```

Save the above script in that directory with filename:

```
$HOME/scripts/gather
```

Make the script executable by typing this into **Terminal**:

```
chmod +x $HOME/scripts/gather
```

Edit your login profile (`$HOME/.profile`) and add your `$HOME/scripts` directory to your PATH:

```
export PATH="$PATH":$HOME/scripts
```

Then start a new **Terminal** and you can use any script that you have saved in `$HOME/scripts` without needing to specify the full path to it, e.g.:

```
gather
```

---

Following information kindly contributed by @user3439894 in comments section, as I am out of my depth on this aspect...

To use a keyboard shortcut, you'd have to create an **Automator** *"Service workflow"* with a *"Run Shell Script"* action, which you can assign a keyboard shortcut to under: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

Comment: You cannot assign a keyboard shortcut to a standalone bash script in macOS under System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Comment: @user3439894 Ok, thank you for the input. As you may have guessed from the way I worded it, it is not something I do myself :-) I guess OP could place the script on his Desktop and double-click it to run it. Or do you have another bright idea to share please? Thanks again.

Comment: To use a keyboard shortcut, you'd have to create an Automator service workflow with a Run Shell Script action, which you can assign a keyboard shortcut to under: System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services

Comment: @user3439894 Many thanks - I have added it to the answer so folks don't miss it.

Comment: This is superb! I am a novice at bash, all the explanations are spot on! Thank you! It does easily search from the selection! Although, if at least 1 file from selection does not exist, it stops and doesn't copy any files. Any chance, to let it continue searching/copying even if it encounters errors?

Comment: I am not sure why that would happen - there must be some error checking in Automator or somewhere. Please try selecting just 2-3 files, one of which doesn't exist, then copy their names to the clipboard. Go in Terminal and run `gather` and see what the output is and paste it into your question, and let me know when you have done it.

Comment: I am ecstatic! I tried restarting my machine, and it worked! Thank you once again!  I mark it as Answered!

Comment: Cool - glad to be of service. Good luck with your project!

Comment: If filenames include spaces you'll need to build the `files` array using something like this; `IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a files <<<"$( printf '%s\n' "$(pbpaste)" )"` instead of `files=( $(pbpaste) )` to avoid undesired results due to word splitting.

Comment: @RobC Yes, I agree. I was answering another question at the same time ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/52075511/2836621 ) where I had checked filenames did not contain spaces as I normally do, but I omitted to do so on this question. OP's example also shows no spaces and OP also says filenames are up to 8 digits. But, yes, you are right - thank you for keeping me honest 